# Eclipse IDE explorer files not in active task dark foreground on dark background

Tags: eclipse, themes

I have chosen the dark theme on Eclipse IDE. I had some issues of dark filenames on dark backgrounds in the project explorer. I was able to solve this by going to [ Menu => Window => Preferences => Appearance => Colors and Fonts => Git ] and so on and changing the foreground colours as required.

This has served me well, except now for when I have installed Mylyn. I have attached a screenshot to show what I am seeing.

The reason I included the tooltip is that the files are a light grey colour if I click the tooltip, which loses the "focus" feature.

I am unable to find the setting for the file names colour when the "Active Task Focus" focus is enabled.

Any guidance where I can change this please?

I am using the latest version of Eclipse and Mylyn

Eclipse Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0) Build id: 20230608-1333
Mylyn version : 3.26

[image]

Comment: Which Eclipse and Mylyn version do you have exactly? They don't seem to be the current ones.

Comment: Great question @howlger. I added the information to the post as I think it is important. It is the latest 2023-06.

Comment: I see and I can reproduce it. It is tracked as [issue #44](https://github.com/eclipse-mylyn/org.eclipse.mylyn/issues/44). Could you help by providing a pull request for that?